# Models with 'hair' does not pose properly!

Tags: modeling, rigging, blender-internal-render-engine

I have an object with a hair emitter, as needed for one of my models. When I rig it and pose, however, the hair goes all wacky and I'm not exactly sure how to fix it. Example:
[image: Weird glitchy hair rig]

How do I fix this?

Comment: not enough information: what is the order of the modifiers? what are the hair settings? have you created enough geometry? did you create a vertex group that's influencing the outcome? try checking all of those

Comment: as @Allofyoush said, not enough info. Better share the blend file with us.